Handmade number sequence puzzle - but I broke it!
Feeling inspired by another 'handmade' sequence puzzle on the site, I decided to try my hand at a similar endeavour myself. But - oops, butterfingers - I appear to have broken it!
I know the sequence begins with:

0, 15, 0, 23, 24, 0, 44, 12, 21, 0, 54, 35, 14, ...

But all of the other digits have become disjointed! I know that the remaining terms (it's a finite sequence) should include 11, 13, 22, 25, 41, 51, 55 and a bunch of zeros, but in what order?
Can you help me repair my sequence? What should it be, and why?

rot13(Rnpu qvtvg qbrfa'g rkprrq 5, fb guvf vf gehyl 'unaqznqr' :) V jnf guvaxvat Oevgvfu Fvta Ynathntr jvgu rnpu qvtvg pbeerfcbaqvat gb gur ahzore bs rkgraqrq svatref ba gur erfcrpgvir unaq, naq znlor gur jubyr frdhrapr sbezvat gur nycunorg, ohg vg qbrfa'g frrz gb jbex...)

I think the digits in this handmade sequence are based on the

 finger names in order:
 1 thumb
 2 index
 3 middle
 4 ring
 5 pinky

And the values are the

 first occurrence of the letters of the alphabet
 a = 0 not present
 b = 1 position 5
 c = 0 not present
 d = 2 position 3
 e = 2 position 4
 f = 0 not present
 g = 4 position 4
 h = 1 position 2
 i = 2 position 1
 j = 0 not present
 k = 5 position 4
 l = 3 position 5
 m = 1 position 4

So the remaining terms are

 n = index = 22
 o = 0
 p = pinky = 51
 q = 0
 r = ring = 41
 s = 0
 t = thumb = 11
 u = thumb = 13
 v = 0
 w = 0
 x = index = 25
 y = pinky = 55
 z = 0

